# Does Laravel Spark handle SCA (strong customer authentication)?

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-spark, strong-customer-authentication

I'm over trying to fumble my way through building a payment system for Laravel with Cashier and Stripe. I got basic payments working, but I need to be able to handle payments with Strong Customer Authentication.

Spark looks like it would be worthwhile if it supports SCA out of the box, but I can't find anything that says it does. Does anyone have experience with this?